# Strong set order

Tags: convex-analysis

I am reading about Monotone Comparative Statics in Levin's lecture notes.
At page 35 there is this picture, which provides an example of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
By the usual definition (Tokpins, 1998):

For two sets of real numbers A and
B, define the binary relation $\leq_{s}$ as follows:
$A \leq_{s} B \quad $ if for any $a \in A$ and $ b \in B$, 
$min\{a,b\} \in A$ and $max\{a,b\} \in B$, so that A is greater than or equal to B in the strong set order.

In the notes the first example $A\leq_s B$ while in the second case this is not true. 
However, I cannot understand the concept. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: These appear to be the same example - how do the sets $A$ and $B$ differ from one figure to the next, otherwise?

Comment: In the second one only the singletons are part of the set I believe

Comment: Note ${1,2,3,4}$ the points in the picture. We then have $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,4\}$.
We have $3\in{A}$ and $2\in{B}$, but $\max{\{2,3\}}=3\notin{B}$.

Comment: Exactly, but then why this reasoning does not apply to the first picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation $ A \leq_s B$ states that $ A $ is a beginning piece of $ A\cup B $ and that $ B$ is an end piece of $ A\cup B$. You see that in t he first example this is the case. However in the second example, $ A$ is a beginning piece of $ A \cup B $, but  $  B $ is not an end piece of $ A\cup B$, since the third point belongs to $ A$  but not to $ B$, anyhow the second point is in $ B $

Comment: exactly, I realised it today: I don't know why I thought it should be mutually exclusive, why is clearly not. Although it is trivial, I will not delete the topic, since I haven't found another talking about the issue